# Showing images outside my application using Tapestry5

Tags: java, tapestry

I am developing my first project with Tapestry and I am about to finish, except for the images..

**What do I want?** I just need to display an image outside my application, example: */home/app/images/image.jpg*

**What did I try?** I have been "googling" and reading Tapestry5 forums, I found this: http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToStreamAnExistingBinaryFile

I followed the steps, creating classes but I need to display the image embed on another page (so I can't use ImagePage), I tried this:

**On page java class**

```
public StreamResponse getImage() {
        InputStream input = DetallesMultimedia.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/home/santi/Escritorio/evolution-of-mario.jpg"); //On application, i will retrieve this from DB
    return new JPEGInline(input,"hellow");
}
```

**On page template**

```
...
<img src="${image}" alt:image/>
...
```

**or**

```
...
${image}
...
```

Obviusly, this didn't work and I really don't know how can I do it. I read about loading the image on an event (returning the OutputStream on that event, as it's said in the HowTo linked above) but my english is so bad (I am sure you already noticed) and I don't understand well how can I do that.

Could you help me please?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen the examples as on the wiki page. Below some code on how to load an image on the classpath though using a StreamResponse.

```
@Inject
private ComponentResources resources;

@OnEvent(value = "GET_IMAGE_STREAM_EVENT")
private Object getProfilePic() throws Exception {


    InputStream openStream = DetallesMultimedia.class.getResourceAsStream("/home/santi/Escritorio/evolution-of-mario.jpg");
    byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(openStream);
    final ByteArrayInputStream output = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);

    final StreamResponse response = new StreamResponse() {

        public String getContentType() {
           "image/jpegOrPngOrGif";
        }

        public InputStream getStream() throws IOException {
            return output;
        }

        public void prepareResponse(Response response) {
            // add response headers if you need to here
        }

    };
    return response;
}

public String getPicUrl() throws Exception {
    return resources.createFormEventLink("GET_IMAGE_STREAM_EVENT");
}
```

In your template:

```
<img src="${picUrl}"/>
```

Comment: Hi joostschouten, thank you for answering. I have a question: What means this line "String uri = empty_profile_pic.toClientURL();
"? Also, I am doing something wrong because the image doesn't load, I got exception (Exception in method es.udc.turismo.web.pages.pdi.multimedia.DetallesMultimedia.onActivate(long), parameter #1: Coercion of picUrl to type java.lang.Long (via String --> Long)). It seems I can't display images in a page with onActivate method :S.

Comment: The line was a mistake. I took the code from my own page which needed this. I now removed it from my answer. As for your exception, you probably have a Long argument in your onActivate method where you activate the page with a string "picUrl". Tapestry can't figure out what Long "picUrl" should be and throws an exception. Remove the argument or provide a proper Coercion.

Comment: Thank you again, joostschouten. If I do the Coercion, what I would fix? I mean, I need onActivation to load other data in my DB. I can't delete onActivation and If I do the Coercion what should I do? Map the String to a 0? I think I have to read more about the concept of Coercion anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: Your onActivate problem is not related to the question here though. That is a different topic I'd like to answer but please do so in another question. If you us my code above as is it should work. Note that I do not use onActivate.

Comment: Sure :), I'm afraid I am not explaining my question. I understand your code and I know it works in a page that not requires external data (I need a key of DB to load some data). So I have to remove onActivate (but I can't!!) or work with Coercion to avoid the exception, am I right? Greetings :)

Comment: The problem is not with the onActivate but the actual activation which you seem to do with the String "picUrl" which Tapestry can't Coerce to a Long, understandably so ;-). So somewhere in your code you are activating the page incorrectly (eg. by use of an ActionLink + context). Another option is to not pass a Long into you activation method but an EventContext and query it for the available parameters.

Comment: Yeah!! I've been working on this for a while and reading a bit about events. In .java I don't know how works `getResourceAsStream()` so I changed this to `InputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);` f is `File f = new File("/home/santi/Escritorio/1.jpg");` now I just have to code my DB calls to retrieve images and it's done. I will post my code later :) I am so grateful joostschouten. Thanks for your patient and sorry for my english :(

Comment: So, my solution was puttin on .tml `<img src="${imgUrl}">`, and on .java I wrote a function wich activates on Event "image" that returns a Stream with the image. The method that calls that event is the posted by joostschouten `return resources.createFormEventLink("image");` Thank you, it works :)

Comment: Nkvnkv: Please start a new post with your specific problems as we run this solution in our production environment and it most certainly works. Short comments like this are not useful and will give people the wrong impression.